# Points in the limit of axis are being plotted outside in matlab, how to avoid it?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm plot a graphic like this one

```
plot(1:10,[0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6],'-xr','linewidth',2,'markersize',10); hold on ;
```

and as is possible to see in this

[image: figure]

that it is not clipping the graphic properly, as parts of the points are outside the axis region.

I already tried a few combinations of tags like these one

```
set(gca,'layer','top','clipping','on',...
    'clippingstyle','rectangle','Xlim',[1 10],'Ylim',[0 6])
```

but it does not solve the issue.  Also, I cannot modify the limits to have all the data completely inside it.

The problem is that the limit of the graph and the data value are the same. If the axis is changed to a slightly smaller value, the points and line vanish completely, not showing the the region that should still be inside the graphic.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I'm confused about why you can't modify the limits to fit your needs?

Comment: Why can't you modify the limits? The solution is there, but if you choose not to use it, well, its hard to help you!

Comment: I need the space to show other things, changing the points in a way that it got the marks in an acceptable way, disturbs the graph. Well, i could do that, but i would need to redo all the graphs in a completely different manner. Based on it, i'm trying to find a work around through clipping, but without a success.

Comment: My personal opinion is that clipping (i.e. showing points with a different markings because they are in the corners) is a bad way of showing data, as one needs to be consistent with data cisualization

Comment: @AnderBiguri. True, have not thought the change of mark style (i indeed can't do that either). In this case i will need to restructure all the graphs and it dependencies. Thanks for the consistency point, i completely forgot about it.

Comment: I think you can get away with just adding a little margin there, an small one. That shoudl not mess the rest of the plot